# Zend Framework changing MySQL results?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

So I have a MySQL database with cities/counties within the United States with longitude and latitude.

This is the query we are using to get results within 10 miles on any position for this example.

`SELECT city, state,((ACOS(SIN('38.2966016' * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS('38.2966016' * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(('-77.634079'-lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance FROM zcta HAVING distance <= '10' ORDER BY distance ASC`

When testing in Sequel Pro results come back as expected:

```
Fredericksburg      VA  4.5932632328546
Spotsylvania        VA  6.1939678870939
Richardsville       VA  6.8293644913069
Locust Grove        VA  7.6479616882979
Hartwood            VA  7.6509448009002
Fredericksburg      VA  7.8178182509761
Fredericksburg      VA  7.8328645163604
Fredericksburg      VA  7.8499527233007
Fredericksburg      VA  7.8832043684573
Fredericksburg      VA  8.8620101042208
```

However when plugged into the following Zend Framework:

```
    $db = $this->getAdapter();
    $sql = "SELECT city, state,((ACOS(SIN('38.2965709' * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS('38.2965709' * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(('-77.6340366'-lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` FROM `zcta` HAVING `distance`<='10' ORDER BY `distance` ASC";
    //$sql = "SELECT city, state,((ACOS(SIN('".$lat."' * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS('".$lat."' * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(('".$lon."'-lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` FROM `zcta` HAVING `distance`<='10' ORDER BY `distance` ASC";
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $rows;
```

We get results (Order by closes)

```
Champlain, VA
Hustle, VA
Caret, VA
Tappahannock, VA
Loretto, VA
```

Champlain, VA is over 39 miles away. It's the same query, I even tested it within shell and got the same results as the Sequel Pro Fredericksburg results. Because of this I'm assuming Zend Framework is changing something when querying the database, thus the Champlain, VA results.

I am a newbie to ZF so is there something I'm missing to get ZF to return the results correctly?

Comment: Zend is just trying to expand our horizon.

Comment: Seriously though, I can't see how this query could get altered like that. You are not using any variables inside the ZF code? You are aware that there are slight differences in the starting positions of the two queries you show?

Comment: try $rowset = $db->fetchAll($sql);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never heard of this problem. Have you tried to remove any quotes from Integers/Floats of your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT city, state,((ACOS(SIN(38.2965709 * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS(38.2965709 * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS((-77.6340366-lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` FROM `zcta` HAVING `distance`<=10 ORDER BY `distance` ASC";
```

Comment: Was complaining about longitude minus sign in another ZF query format so I had quoted them. That helped!

Answer (score 1):

Compare with 10 as number. The query seems to work for me after removing '' from '10'.